# Variable naming of instances in Python

Tags: python, class, dynamic, instance, naming

I want to do the following thing:

```
f = SomeClass()
something(f.name) = deepcopy(f)
```

So when f.name == 'ABC' I have an instance of SomeClass() called ABC.

What do I need that for?  I want to loop trough a list, and every element of the list should be an instance of SomeClass() but with a specific name that gets generated during the instancing.

Comment: What do you want to do with that specific name?

Comment: One place to "construct" such a name would be in the `__str__(self)` method.

Comment: It is unclear to me if you want to set a `name` attribute of an instance, or if you want to name the variable?

Answer (score 0):

You need a dictionary , which stores `key`:`value` pairs, the key can be the name , and the value can be the instance directly. You would also need to note that the `keys` in dictionaries are unique , so if you try to set value for a key that already exists in the dictionary, it would overwrite the previous value.

Example -

```
>>> class CA:
...     def __init__(self, name):
...             self.name = name
...
>>> classdict = {}
>>> classdict['abcd'] = CA('abcd')
>>> classdict['bcde'] = CA('bcde')
>>> classdict
{'abcd': <__main__.CA object at 0x02265150>, 'bcde': <__main__.CA object at 0x02265250>}
>>> for key in classdict:
...     print(classdict[key].name)
...
abcd
bcde
```

Comment: You could just as well store the instances in a list; each element will know its name attribute.

Comment: Yes, but you would not be able to access the element using the `name` attribute. Though that has not specifically been asked in the question, I am guessing that is a requirement since he wants to do something like - `something(f.name) = <something>` .

Comment: I don't think that's a requirement in the question. The OP just seems to want each instance to have a separate name attribute.

Comment: Also, I do not see any benefit of using a list over dictionary in this case, both may be same.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by modifying the scope dictionaries returned by [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#locals) or [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#globals):

```
from copy import deepcopy

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

f = SomeClass('ABC')

locals()[f.name] = deepcopy(f)

print(ABC)
```

I must note though that in most cases it is bad practice.